# Ubuntu 22.04 on Hyper-v

Tags: hyper-v

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Hyper-V, but I'm experiencing a laggy mouse cursor.

I added 4 virtual processors and 8GB of RAM, it still moving like pentium 1. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Have you looked at the graphical (GPU/video) settings instead of the CPU/RAM settings?

Comment: The information is a bit thin... My Ubuntu installation on Hyper-V perform well (=fluent) with less RAM and less virtual CPUs.
Please add information about our graphics card, how graphics are setup in Hyper-V and which CPU the host system is using.

Comment: Check the images that i've added. What could i check o nthe gpu settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I was testing with a CentOS image, and it's performing similarly to Ubuntu when I'm creating it manually. I've discovered that if I create the Ubuntu VM using the Quick Create option, it works fine with no lag or sizing issues.

Ubuntu 22.04:

[image: Ubuntu]

CentOS:

[image: CentOS]